# Cannot Resolve Method i(java.lang.String)

Tags: android, logcat

I'm trying to make a simple button that when clicked will display "Hello" to the logs in Android Studio. However I get this message on my last line of code: Cannot Resolve Method i(java.lang.String)

Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickMeFunctionButton2(View view){

         Log.i("Hello");
    }
```

Here's an image

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct code is:

```
    Log.i("TAG", "msg");
```

Comment: you need to pass 2 string type arguments to Log.i method

Answer (score 3):

```
Log.i(TAG,"msg hello");
```

You have to use TAG as class name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass 2 string type arguments to `Log.i` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public void clickMeFunctionButton2(View view){

             Log.i("TAG","Hello");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code also include an explanation of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void clickMeFunctionButton2(View view){
         String TAG = "YourClassName_OR_Anything";
         Log.i(TAG, "Hello");
    }
```